# Why do autocite return the input and not the index of citation the input refers to?

Tags: latex, biblatex

When I try this code, which me (and my friend) agree that should result in \autocite{SML} returning this: [1]. Instead it returns [SML] and gives the warnings.

1. Citation 'SML' on page 1 undefined
2. There were undefined references.

```
\usepackage{biblatex}

\autocite[SML]

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[1]{SML}
    Sebastian van de Linde, Anna Löschberger, Teresa Klein, Meike Heidbreder, Steve Wolter, Mike Heilemann, Markus Sauer 
    \textit{Direct stochastic optical reconstruction microscopy with standard fluorescent probes}. Nature Protocols. 2011 16. June;VOL.6 NO.7;991-1009

\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with the way you set bibliography, but `\autocite` excepts a maximum of three input arguments. Where the fist two are additional arguments such as page or chapter reference. The third one is you bibtexkey and needs to be put in `{}`.

Which is why typing `\autocite{SML}` should work for you.